# How to use a link instead of the normal file input button to explorer files and folders

Tags: javascript, html, css, file

I would like to create a link which when clicked shows the file/folder explorer, instead of the usual file-input (file explorer button) ussually used in web pages. Is this really possible?

The only way I've managed to go about it is using the [Bootstrap FileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/), which is, however, still a button, al·be·it better looking than the default file WW3 input button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"> </script>
```

**Via JavaScript:**

```
$(":file").filestyle({badge: false});
```

**Via data attributes:**

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-badge="false">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
<input id="input_file" type="file" style="display:none;">
<a href="#"><label for="input_file">Trigger the file input</label></a>
```

Though, wrapping a label with an anchor is not a valid HTML. I recommend using jQuery or Javascript to do the job.

Here's the example using jQuery to achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#trigger-input-file").click(function(){
    $('input[type="file"]').trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="input-file" style="display:none;">

<a href="#"><label for="input-file">Trigger input file without script</label></a><br><br>
<a href="#" id="trigger-input-file">Trigger input file with the jQuery script</a>
```

Hope this help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

sure. mask over input

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  }
label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
a {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" id="qwe">
  <label for="qwe"><a href="">Select a file</a></label>
</div>
```

Comment: the OP asked for a link not a button.

Comment: for understanding the decisions of principle it does not matter

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
<input id="file" type="file">
```

and for the file explorer link this:

```
<a href="#"><label for="file">test</label></a>
```

here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1qztex41/

As @Jandroide mention, use `#file { display: none; }`

Comment: This is invalid HTML. A label may not be a descendant of an anchor.

Comment: A bad example, one should follow HTML rules.

Comment: @Evolutio — The OP did not ask for a solution that depended on invalid HTML or one that used a label.